# Notice: Undefined index php sdk for Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I send a Facebook request using Graph api and i get the Array below as a result. However when i am trying to execute the code:

`$a=count($Obj_1['events']->data);`

I get the following message

> Notice: Undefined index: events

I have tried everything like:

```
$Obj_1[0]->events->data
$Obj_1->events->data                 
$Object[0]->['events']->data
```

and googled anything trying to figure this out.
I am trying to get rid of the Notice because the script runs as intended...
Pls help :)

```
 Array(
        [events] => stdClass Object
            (
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => 
                                [start_time] => 
                                [timezone] => 
                                [id] => 
                            )

                    )

                [paging] => stdClass Object
                    (

                       )
            )
        [id] => 
    )
```

Comment: What is your main variable & `var_dump` result?  or show your some code section..

Comment: Obj_1 = GetallEvents($Venue_IDs[$i]);   GetallEvents asks graph api to take events from some facebook pages as an array like this    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray(); then i return the result back at the script and i want to take how many events exist in the same page   var_dump gave results 0  and 1 and 4

Comment: var_dump($Obj_1);  Gave this output                                                                                                         array (size=2)
  'events' => 
    object(stdClass)[14]
      public 'data' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[4]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[9]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'next' => string 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/.../ (length=154)
  'id' => string '387929384628068' (length=15)

Comment: what is output of `var_dump($Obj_1);` ?

Comment: i hope understand your problem to see your code sample.. so, show your code section..

Comment: The code for GetallEvents                                                                                  if(isset($session)) 
{$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET','/'.$venueID.'?fields=events');$response = $request->execute();$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();return $graphObject;} and my main: if ($result->num_rows > 0)                {
   $venue_count=0;
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   {
    $Venue_IDs[$venue_count]= (string) $row["ID"];
    $venue_count++;
   }}
  $k=0;
  for($i= 0; $i<$venue_count;$i++)$Obj_1 = GetallEvents($Venue_IDs[$i]);

Comment: update your question with code

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ll60qhkfj46l47/GetFBevents.php?dl=0                                https://www.dropbox.com/s/ua35ioogpq6zy2l/FBevent_functions.php?dl=0

Comment: I think copy paste problem.  try with: remove some code and type code. it may have hidden char.  sometimes i face like problem..  and wait. i am trying.

Comment: i check it .Also i get the same notice in line 80 ($event_place = $Obj ['place']->{'name'};  at the funtions file..

Comment: wait..  what is line no of dropbox..   80 is right?

Comment: when i try to get the place property from the Object for longitude and latitude gives me the same notice

Comment: this may not return `GetallEvents($Venue_IDs[$i]);` function..

Answer (score 0):

**Try replace:**  if `print_r($Obj_1);` line do work then replace following..
From

```
$a=count($Obj_1['events']->data);
```

To

```
$tmpObj=$Obj_1["events"];
$a=count($tmpObj->data);
```

Comment: Same. Still gives me the Notice: Undefined index: events on    $tmpObj=$Obj_1["events"];      and   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on $a=count($tmpObj->data);

Comment: This is very Strange! you may try  create a new file.

Comment: Is there any way that the problem is because i call a function???
I did the same thing without calling any function , in a single php file and didn't give me any NOTICE problem.....